# mechanize - how to select links based on adjacent tags?

Tags: python, mechanize

I would like to parse a search result list and only follow links for results that match certain criteria.

lets say the results has such a structure:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <!-- in here there is a list of information such as: 
           height: xx  price: xx , and a link <a> to the page -->
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <!-- next item -->
  .
  .
  .
```

I want qulify each item in the list against a set of criteria ( height > x, price < x ), and follow the link if the item matches.

Some how I need to reference a tag that is the child of another tag (ie the  element that is the child of the first

element)

I'm pretty sure the solution would be along one of these lines, but I dont what library and/or methods to use:

1 - using some library I parse the list into an object so that I can do this:

```
for item in list:
  if item['price'] < x:
    br.follow_link(item.link)
```

2- I seek the html response till I find the first "price" text, parse the value and qualify it, and if it qualifies, follow the link that is adjacent to that point of the html string (in my case, the link appears before the info, so I need to select the link that appears BEFORE the the matched info.

I can think of some super brute force, low level, methods of doing this, but I was wondering if there is a library or mechanize method I can use. 
THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library called [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). This will be the outline of your code while parsing with Beautiful Soup.

Suppose your html is:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
        height: 10  price: 20
        <a href="google.com">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
        height: 30  price: 40
        <a href="facebook.com">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
        height: 50  price: 60
        <a href="stackoverflow.com">
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Your code to parse would be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Read the input file. I am assuming the above html is part of test.html
html = ""
with open('test.html', 'r') as htmlfile:
    for line in htmlfile:
        html += line
htmlfile.close()

bs = BeautifulSoup(html)
links_to_follow = []


ul = bs.find('ul')
for li in ul.find_all('li'):
    height = int(li.find('div').get_text().strip().split()[1])
    price = int(li.find('div').get_text().strip().split()[3])
    if height > 10 and price > 20: # I am assuming this to be the criteria
        links_to_follow.append(li.find('a').get('href'))

print links_to_follow
```

This gives:

```
facebook.com
stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: Wow thanks! I had seen beautifulsoup before, but I wasnt sure how I can get it to find only within one tag element. So by looking at your code, I conclude that when I do element.find('tag'), it only looks for 'tag' inside 'element'. That's the key right there. Thank you!